# ssh accepts only the half password

Tags: linux, password

my passwort for login into ssh has 16 characters. but I can login if I only type the first 8 carachters of the password ...

I did this in /etc/login.defs:

```
PASS_MAX_DAYS   99999
PASS_MIN_DAYS   0
PASS_MIN_LEN    16
PASS_WARN_AGE   7
PASS_MAX_LEN    16
```

But I can still login with the first 8 characters of my passwort.
All 16 characters should be checked, how to do this?

Comment: What version of Linux?

Comment: I suspect you're using DES password encryption, which only supports a maximum of 8 characters.

Comment: CentOS:  2.6.18-274.3.1.el5

this are the last lines of /etc/login.defs

# Use MD5 or DES to encrypt password? Red Hat use MD5 by default.
MD5_CRYPT_ENAB yes

ENCRYPT_METHOD MD5

Comment: Restart the ssh daemon?

Comment: @Danzzz Sure, but check what the password is stored as right now.  If it's stored as DES, then it's got to validate as DES - which means truncating to 8 characters.

Comment: how to check this? in login.defs file ENCRYPT_METHOD MD5